# Java JFrame window is clipped under Win10, but not under MacOS

Tags: java, swing, windows-10, jframe, jcomponent

I'm developing an educational app for Mac and Win10.

My canvas window inherits from JFrame, and is declared to be a fixed size:

```
        setSize(1250,732);
        setMinimumSize(getSize()); //fixed window size
        setMaximumSize(getSize());
```

The interactive content of the window is done in a JComponent descendant, which I add to the frame with:

```
        getContentPane().add(new CartesianCanvas());
```

The CartesianCanvas is sized equally its parent JFrame.

The window is clipped when launched under Win10 -- about 15 pixels in width and height are missing on the right and bottom edges.   What gives?

Comment: *"declared to be a fixed size"* That's the wrong size (for any but your machine, with the PLAF you're using, with the Java version you're.. In fact, I'll just add my copy/paste comment. After figuring how to layout the components, call `pack()` for the right size. **Here is the comment:** Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or ..

Comment: .. [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0):

The code fragment above is not the correct way to make a window not resizeable.   The correct approach is:

setResizable(false);

That said, with the plethora of viewing device options and resolutions (including multiple monitors, TV interfaces and projectors), it might be time for frameworks like Java, .Net and JS to revamp their graphics libraries to provide an alternative to pixel-based coordinates?

All app developers are facing this same problem.  It makes little sense to force each app developer into writing code that could be generalized at the system level.  Agree?  Disagree?